# Creating a mixin that notifies a banner at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a page that creates a pop-up notification whenever a message is broadcasted from another user. The pop-up is basically a div that holds content from the sent message with a button that allows you to close it.

Now I've researched a million ways to create transitions that extend properties using pseudo classes but my question is this: Is it possible to create a banner at the top of the page that slides down with the message when it's sent by another using pure CSS3 / transition mixins?

My thought was to transition the max-height property but obviously it isn't working. I'm assuming because there is no height to begin with.

CSS:

```
.banner-messages {
 > div {
  background-color: #74bce7;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: relative; 
  line-height: 100%;    
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  z-index: 1000; 
  overflow-y: hidden;

  @include drop-down;
  }
}

@mixin drop-down {
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1.5s linear;
  transition: all 1.5s linear;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="banner-messages" data-bind="foreach: messages">
<div class="banner-message">
    <img data-bind="imgSrc: 'radio.svg'">

    <div class="banner-body">
        <p class="banner-title">{{title}}</p>
        <pre>{{message}}</pre>
    </div>

    <span class="exit-dialout-panel icon icon-closes" data-bind="visible: dismissable, click: $parent.dismissMessage.bind($parent, $data)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a class with the `css` binding that applies `transform: translateY`:

```js
var Viewmodel = function Viewmodel() {
  var that = this;
  
  this.messages = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  this.removeMessages = function removeMessages() {
    that.messages.removeAll();
  };
  
  this.addMessage = function addMessage() {
    that.messages.push("A new message came in");
  };
};

ko.applyBindings( new Viewmodel() );
```

```css
header {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translateY(-110%);
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <header data-bind="css: { active: messages().length > 0 }">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: messages">
      <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click: removeMessages">mark all as read</button>
  </header>
</main>

<button data-bind="click: addMessage">Add message</button>
```

Comment: transform works perfectly with translateY! I'll definitely try this approach later. However this toggles a message up and down while in real life the message will be sent dynamically by the sender and then closed by the sendee whenever they don't want to see it anymore. I'm not using jQuery and probably won't for this project but still a +1 for the transition. Thanks.

Comment: @user3802738 I couldn't fully gather from your question which area you were having trouble with. I focused on CSS and only used jQ for demonstration purposes; give me a minute, I'll rewrite it into a Knockout-based solution. Edit: done!

Comment: Quick and fast. Thanks for closing the door on this one and providing an example!